# SDL_surface to OpenGL texture

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, textures

Hey, I have this script to load a SDL_Surface and save it as a OpenGL texture:

```
typedef GLuint texture;

texture load_texture(std::string fname){
    SDL_Surface *tex_surf = IMG_Load(fname.c_str());
    if(!tex_surf){
        return 0;
    }
    texture ret;
    glGenTextures(1, &ret);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ret);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, tex_surf->w, tex_surf->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex_surf->pixels);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    SDL_FreeSurface(tex_surf);
    return ret;
}
```

The problem is that it isn't working. When I call the function from the main function, it just doesn't load any image (when displaying it's just turning the drawing color), and when calling from any function outside the main function, the program crashes.
It's this line that makes the program crash:

```
2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, tex_surf->w, tex_surf->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex_surf->pixels);
```

Can anybody see a mistake in this?

Comment: Post a minimal, compilable source that demonstrates your problem. You will get better answers. It is very difficult to theorize what the problem is otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

My bet is you need to convert the SDL_Surface before trying to cram it into an OpenGL texture. Here's something that should give you the general idea:

```
SDL_Surface* originalSurface; // Load like an other SDL_Surface

int w = pow(2, ceil( log(originalSurface->w)/log(2) ) ); // Round up to the nearest power of two

SDL_Surface* newSurface = 
  SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, w, w, 24, 0xff000000, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0);
SDL_BlitSurface(originalSurface, 0, newSurface, 0); // Blit onto a purely RGB Surface

texture ret;

glGenTextures( 1, &ret );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, ret );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, w, w, 0, GL_RGB,
          GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, newSurface->pixels );
```

[I found the original code here](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/viewreply.asp?ID=1442518). There may be some [other useful posts on GameDev](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/viewreply.asp?ID=1437342) as well.

Comment: Without more source it would be very hard to determine why your blitting is not working. Can you post the code you use to render?

Comment: Why are you using `ceil()` instead of `round()`?

Comment: @ShambhavGautam hard to say since I posted this 11 years ago, but likely it's because `round()` can round down and I only ever want to round up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies probably in 3rd argument (`internalformat`) of the call to `glTexImage2D`.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, tex_surf->w, tex_surf->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex_surf->pixels);
```

You have to use constants like `GL_RGB` or `GL_RGBA` because the actual values of the macro are not related to the number of color components.

A list of allowed values is in the reference manual: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml .

This seems to be a frequent mistake. Maybe some drivers are just clever and correct this, so the wrong line might still work for some people.

```
/usr/include/GL/gl.h:473:#define GL_RGB             0x1907
/usr/include/GL/gl.h:474:#define GL_RGBA            0x1908
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're doing this somewhere outside your code snippet, but have you called

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

at some point?

Comment: Not only does this not help at all, it might even cause an error in your OpenGL context because fixed pipeline texturing is deprecated in newer OpenGL versions.

Answer (score 0):

Some older hardware (and, surprisingly, emscripten's opengl ES 2.0 emulation, running on the new machine I bought this year) doesn't seem to support textures whose dimensions aren't powers of two.  That turned out to be the problem I was stuck on for a while (I was getting a black rectangle rather than the sprite I wanted).  So it's possible the poster's problem would go away after resizing the image to have dimensions that are powers of two.

See: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/NPOT_Texture